# Add a line as a selection indicator to a UITabbarItem in Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I wanna use a thick line at the bottom of a UITabbarItems as a selection indicator. Due to the fact that the App must work on different phone sizes, I cannot use a image as selection indicator. That's why I think I have to use Swift to do this. (The line has to be 1/3 of page width).

I tried to use `UITabBarItem.appearance()` but without success.

Comment: you can use an `UIView` and set the selected background color for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Features of this tiny code snippet:

- width is dynamic
- it is animated
- it is a lot more customizable for future features

  ```
  class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

  let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
  let indicatorHeight: CGFloat = 5
  var indicatorWidth: CGFloat!
  let indicatorBottomMargin: CGFloat = 2
  let indicatorLeftMargin: CGFloat = 2

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // setup tabbar indicator
      rectShape.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
      indicatorWidth = view.bounds.maxX / 2 // count of items
      self.tabBarController!.view.layer.addSublayer(rectShape)
      self.tabBarController?.delegate = self

      // initial position
      updateTabbarIndicatorBySelectedTabIndex(0)
  }

  func updateTabbarIndicatorBySelectedTabIndex(index: Int) -> Void
  {
      let updatedBounds = CGRect( x: CGFloat(index) * (indicatorWidth + indicatorLeftMargin),
                                  y: view.bounds.maxY - indicatorHeight,
                                  width: indicatorWidth - indicatorLeftMargin,
                                  height: indicatorHeight)

      let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
      CGPathAddRect(path, nil, updatedBounds)
      rectShape.path = path
  }
  }

  extension FirstViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

  func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
      updateTabbarIndicatorBySelectedTabIndex(tabBarController.selectedIndex)
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice solution. Have you tried this? I mean when I run this code, it works fine for first tab. After I click on second tab, the indicator is showing upper side of the tabbar.

Comment: Instead of `view.bounds.maxY` you should use `(tabBarController?.view.bounds.maxY)!`

Answer (score 21):

You can do it with add custom image, that will be created in your code, to `selectionIndicatorImage` on your `UITabBar` object. For example you can create `extension` for `UIImage` class like this:

```
extension UIImage {
    func createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, size.height - lineWidth, size.width, lineWidth))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

And call it in your first loaded `ViewController` like this:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tabBar = self.tabBarController!.tabBar
        tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicator(UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count), tabBar.frame.height), lineWidth: 2.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

In this case result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution but your extension really should be a class function, currently you're initialising two `UIImage`s.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3:**

```
extension UIImage {
    func createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :size.height - lineHeight), size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: lineHeight)))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tabBar = self.tabBarController!.tabBar
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count), height: tabBar.frame.height), lineHeight: 2.0)
}
```

Comment: thank you, but in iphone X 11.2, this is not working, means 2.0px bar is not aligning with tarbar, its going 20pix down. Any idea?

Comment: @SureshDurishetti call you function in willlayoutSubviews function and it will be working great

Answer (score 10):

Swift 4.x
Xcode 10.x

```
extension UIImage {
    func createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(x: 0, y: size.height - lineWidth, width: size.width, height: lineWidth))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Use

```
tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicator(color: BLUE, size: CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width/CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count), height:  tabBar.frame.height), lineWidth: 2.0)
```