# Swift 4: How to add a circle point as a selection indicator to a UITabbarItem

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a little circle point as indicator to the selected UITabBarItem. How can i do this?

I use a custom UITabBarController. It looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class EventTabBar: UITabBarController {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 79/255, green: 122/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1)
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(red: 198/255, green: 203/255, blue: 209/255, alpha: 1)
    tabBar.isTranslucent = false
    tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

    //Add Shadow to TabBar
    tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.12
    tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 8
    tabBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
   }
}
```

Can i use the `selectionIndicatorImage` to do this?

Hope you can help me. Thanks for your answer

Comment: you can do this in  didSelect method of tabbar ... run a loop on all tabs and remove dot from previous tab  and add it at selectedTab.

Answer (score 2):

```
let size = CGSize(width: tabController.tabBar.frame.width / (amount of items),
                  height: tabController.tabBar.frame.height)

let dotImage = UIImage().createSelectionIndicator(color: .blue, size: size, lineHeight: 7)

tabController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = dotImage
```

-

```
extension UIImage {
    func createSelectionIndicator(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()

        let innerRect = CGRect(x: (size.width/2) - lineHeight/2,
                               y: size.height - lineHeight - 2,
                               width: lineHeight,
                               height: lineHeight)

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: innerRect, cornerRadius: lineHeight/2)
        path.fill()

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy actually. TabBarButton has two properties to set image, one is `TabBarItem.image` and another is `TabBarItem.selectedImage` set an image without the circle point for `TabBarItem.image` property and set an image with circle point for `TabBarItem.selectedImage` property.
If you want to set only the circle point for selected state, set the normal image property to UIImage(). Hope this solves the problem.

```
scanTabBarItem.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .qrcode, textColor: .white, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
scanTabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .addressBook, textColor: .white, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
```

if not to show any image normally,

```
scanTabBarItem.image = UIImage()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... can you give my an example, which i can use it, this would be very helpfully for me, thanks

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: thanks for your update... but, I didn't want to show the circle inficator for the selected tab in the form of an image. I wanted to have it created programmatically. I have seen this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33670450/10183816 how can I change the line to a circle indicator (like the Dock in macOS, when App is running) Hope you can help me again